# Is there a way to remove all occurrences of a particular element with a specific attribute from an xml file?

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, elementtree

I have a bunch of xml files that I want to remove an element called **uid** with the attribute **type = uri** from. There are other instances of the element **uid** but I just want to remove the ones with the **type=uri** attribute. The number and structure of occurrences of the element in each xml file is different.

I tried `root.findall("//uid[@type='uri']")` and tried using the `remove()` method to remove all occurrences of the element. But this doesn't work. I am unable to used a fixed XPATH because that isn't going to work for all the xml files.

For example :

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <uid type ="x"> This needs to stay </uid>
    </c>
    <d>
      <uid type ="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    </d>
    <e>
      <uid type ="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    <e>
  </b>
</a>
```

I tried doing

```
for uid in a.iter("//unitid[@type='uri']"):
    a.remove(uid)
```

I also tried using `a.find()` and `a.findall()`. The script doesn't throw any errors but doesn't do what's required as well.

I am fairly new to xml parsing using ElementTree so I apologize for my naivety
.Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is better to use XSLT for such tasks

Comment: How should look like your result xml tree? For remove(subelement) node you have to find the parent node, not the child himself, see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)

Comment: your xml has a failure at the tag `<e>` => missing closing tag `</e>`.

Answer (score 2):

In XSLT 3.0:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0">
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  <xsl:template match="*[@type='uri']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It's also easy enough in XSLT 1.0, just a bit more verbose, if you don't want to install a 3.0 processor.

Explanation: `on-no-match="shallow-copy"` means that if there's no specific rule for a particular element or attribute, it gets copied unchanged. The single `xsl:template` rule says that when you find a matching element, no output is produced: that is, it gets deleted.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be to find all parent tags (which have `<uid type="uri">` as a child) and then remove those children:

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_data = """
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <uid type="x"> This needs to stay </uid>
    </c>
    <d>
      <uid type="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    </d>
    <e>
      <uid type="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    </e>
  </b>
</a>
"""

root = ET.fromstring(xml_data)

# this will find all tags that have <uid type="uri"> as child
parents = root.findall('.//uid[@type="uri"]...')

for p in parents:
    p.remove(p.find('./uid[@type="uri"]'))

print(ET.tostring(root).decode())
```

Prints:

```xml
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <uid type="x"> This needs to stay </uid>
    </c>
    <d>
      </d>
    <e>
      </e>
  </b>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your XML tree a bit and show you another scenario:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_sample="""
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <uid type ="x"> This needs to stay </uid>
    </c>
    <d>
      <uid type ="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    </d>
    <e>
      <uid type ="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
    </e>
    <f>
      <uid type ="uri"> This has to be removed </uid>
      <other/>
    </f>
  </b>
</a>
"""
root = ET.fromstring(xml_sample)

for parent in root.findall("b"):
    for child in parent.findall('.//uid[@type="uri"]/..'):
        # check if uid is the only content, than remove complete empty branch
        if len(list(child.iterfind("*"))) == 1:
            parent.remove(child)
        else:
            # otherwise remove <uid>-tag only.
            uid = child.find("uid")
            child.remove(uid)
            
ET.indent(root, space='  ')
ET.dump(root)
```

Output:

```
<a>
  <b>
    <c>
      <uid type="x"> This needs to stay </uid>
    </c>
    <f>
      <other />
    </f>
  </b>
</a>
```